# "Unused import statement" al importar from django.http import HttpResponse

Tags: python, django

Que tal ? al parecer tengo todo bien en el codigo solo que al momento de cargar el django.http import HttpResponse me aparece una leyenda que dice "Unused import statement" 
a que se deberia ?

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import  HttpResponse #aqui es donde me aparece el "Unused import statement"
from .forms import pacienteForm


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'paciente/index.html')


def paciente_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = pacienteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            form = pacienteForm()

        return render(request, 'paciente/paciente_form.html', {'form':form})
```

Este es el codigo de urls.py. No se si tenga algun error en esta parte. al parecer esta todo bien y en orden

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from apps.paciente.views import index, paciente_view


urlpatterns = [
   url('$', index, name='index'),
   url('nuevo$', paciente_view, name='paciente_crear'),

]
```

este es el codigo de forms.py. en esta parte lo que busco es crear un formulario que se pueda aplicar en la url paciente/nuevo. 
ya lo probe y no me lo carga.

```
from django import forms
from .models import paciente


class pacienteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = paciente

        fields = [

            'nombre',
            'apellidoMaterno',
            'apellidoPaterno',
            'TipoDeSangre',
            'FechaDeNacimiento',
            'sexo',
            'edad',
        ]

    labels = {

            'nombre': 'Nombre',
            'apellidoMaterno': 'Apellido Materno',
            'apellidoPaterno ': 'Apellido Paterno',
            'TipoDeSangre ': 'Tipo de Sangre',
            'FechaDeNacimiento': 'Fecha de Nacimiento',
            'sexo': 'Sexo',
            'edad': 'Edad',

    }

    widgets = {

            'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'apellidoMaterno': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'apellidoPaterno ': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'TipoDeSangre ': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'FechaDeNacimiento': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'sexo': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'edad': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

    }
```

Debido a esto, no me carga el formulario en la pagina

Comment: Hola Salvador, eso no es un error como tal, es un aviso del analizador de código de tu IDE indicándote que importas algo que no usas. Elimina ese import si realmente no va a ser necesario.

Comment: que tal ? ya lo hice y sigue sin cargar el formulario

Comment: Vale, eso es otro problema que nada tiene que ver con lo anterior. Para ayudarte creo que deberías considerar agregar más información, como tu `urls.py`, el código de `pacienteForm`, la plantilla, etc en vez de solo la vista.

Comment: claro, lo agrego, un momento